# Question in Fibonacci numbers with R code

Tags: r

In question "Obtain 40 sequence starting with Fibonacci sequence 0."
I found a code like this.

```
a <-c(0,1)
while(length(a)<40){
   position <- length(a)
   new <- a[position] + a[position-1]
   a<-c(a,new)
   }
print(a)
```

But I don't understand why I have to add `a<-c(a,new)`.

Comment: To accumulate the history of the generated sequence so far.

Comment: `a` is your vector of numbers, and that statement just adds the new number onto the end each time

Comment: Insert a `print(a)` statement after the statement that sets `a` and change 40 to 10, say, to keep the problem small and then run it to get the idea of how `a` keeps all past values (and of course the last two values are needed to compute the next value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `c` function is used to concatenate elements together ([documentation of the c function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/c)).

In the start of the while loop `a` is the vector c(0, 1).

In the first iteration, the variable `new` is calculated and `a` becomes the vector `a` concatenated with the value of `new`, which is 1 in the first iteration.

```
#a before the first iteration a = c(0, 1)
#1st iter:                    a = c(0, 1, 1) <-- calculate new then put it in the vector a
#2nd iter:                    a = c(0, 1, 1, 2)
# ...
```